# How to fix sentry-related yarn error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '.../src/native/node_modules/@sentry'

Tags: react-native, yarnpkg, sentry

I'm attempting to install new packages in my react-native project via yarn but am caught up by the above error message.

I've installed react-native-sentry via npm rather than yarn. Any attempt to uninstall and unlink from the rest of the project doesn't help. No other suggestions posted (https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-electron/issues/94) have gotten me past this first error. Any subsequent attempt to build in Xcode after this initial `yarn` error gives me tons more errors.

My (truncated) `src/native/package.json`:

```
{
    "name": "native",
    .
    . 
    .
    "workspaces": {
        "nohoist": ["@sentry", "@sentry/**"]
    },
    .
    . 
    .
    },
    "dependencies": {
        .
        . 
        .
        "react-native-sentry": "^0.39.0",
```

The initial error:

```
$ yarn
yarn install v1.16.0
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
[2/4]   Fetching packages...
[3/4]   Linking dependencies...
warning " > [XXXX].shared-components@1.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "react@^16.5.0".
warning "workspace-aggregator-ad0ee18a-71f6-4b7e-ae5b-7d9c0089e4da > hydrated-oauth-redux > @callstack/async-storage@1.1.0" has unmet peer dependency "react-native@^0.38".
warning "workspace-aggregator-ad0ee18a-71f6-4b7e-ae5b-7d9c0089e4da > hydrated-oauth-redux > babel-jest@22.4.4" has unmet peer dependency "babel-core@^6.0.0 || ^7.0.0-0".
warning "workspace-aggregator-ad0ee18a-71f6-4b7e-ae5b-7d9c0089e4da > native > enzyme-adapter-react-16@1.11.2" has unmet peer dependency "react-dom@^16.0.0-0".

error An unexpected error occurred: "ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '[XXXX]/src/native/node_modules/@sentry'".

info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "[XXXX]/yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
```

This causes a subsequent error in Xcode when attempting to run the app in the simulator, forcing me to restore my entire project to a prior commit.

```
/Users/[XXXX]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/[XXXX]/Build/Intermediates.noindex/[XXXX].build/Debug-iphonesimulator/[XXXX].build/Script-00DD1BFF1BD5951E006B06BC.sh: line 5: export: `/[XXXX]/src/native/ios/.."': not a valid identifier
/Users/[XXXX]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/[XXXX]/Build/Intermediates.noindex/[XXXX].build/Debug-iphonesimulator/[XXXX].build/Script-00DD1BFF1BD5951E006B06BC.sh: line 7: ../node_modules/@sentry/cli/bin/sentry-cli: No such file or directory
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

Many others have faced a [similar error](https://github.com/getsentry/react-native-sentry/issues/401), yet I don't believe it's the root of my issue. None of their solutions have helped.

I have tried uninstalling sentry and completely wiping every mention from the project, reverting to previous commits, reinstalling nvm and yarn and react-native-sentry through multiple package managers, but no luck.